# WPF|Avalonia Передать биндинг в UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, avalonia

Есть юзерконтрол с ToggleSwitch (или CheckBox, не важно). Как я могу передать из основного окна в IsChecked юзерконтрола биндинг, чтобы в ToggleSwitch свойство IsChecked биндилось к нему?
Следующий очевидный вариант не работает.
Код Window.axaml:

```
<uc:ToggleBox IsChecked="{Binding MyViewModelProp}"/>
```

Код в ToggleBox.cs (в WPF может быть иначе):

```
private bool _isChecked;
        public bool IsChecked
        {
            set => this.SetAndRaise(IsCheckedProperty, ref _isChecked, value);
            get => _isChecked;
        }
        public static DirectProperty<ToggleBox, bool> IsCheckedProperty =
            AvaloniaProperty.RegisterDirect<ToggleBox, bool>(
                nameof(IsChecked),
                o => o.IsChecked,
                (o, v) => o.IsChecked = v);
```

Код в ToggleBox.axaml:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
...
<ToggleSwitch IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
```

Подобным образом я делал свойство Title, но передавал в него не биндинг, а статичный текст, и это работает. А вот с передачей биндинга проблемы. Контекст передается, я проверял.

Comment: Не нужно никуда ничего передавать. Есть вьюмодели и все биндятся на них.

Comment: Мне нужно создать вьюмодель контрола?

Comment: 1 У вас так то одно окно, а значит никто не запрещает делать `RelativeSource + FindAncestor` чтобы добраться до вашего IsChecked. 2 С MVVM проще, ведь она передается через DataContext и `RelativeSource` не нужен. (конечно если вы не создаете переиспользуемый контрол, который ничего не должен знать про внешний мир)

Comment: Это как раз переиспользуемый контрол. И в каждом случае для IsChecked идет биндинг к какой-либо DTO.

Comment: Кажется я понял. Вы запутали со своей фразой "передача биндинга". Вы пишете свой контрол. У контрола делаете свойства `DependencyProperty` (как я они же `DirectProperty`). Снаружи контрола все биндятся к этим свойствам. Внутри контрола тоже нужно биндиться к этим свойствам. Если все видят свойства верно, то проверьте `Mode`, вдруг он `OneTime` и тогда `ToggleSwitch` просто инициализируется раньше выставления `IsChecked` и игнорит его выставление.

Comment: Странно, но не дело не в Mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело в

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

Он подменяет `DataContext` в месте вызова

```
<uc:ToggleBox IsChecked="{Binding MyViewModelProp}"/>
```

и поэтому он не может найти поле `MyViewModelProp` (что кстати видно в `output` логе)

Так что нельзя подменять DataContext внутри контрола, а следует делать примерно так

```
<ToggleSwitch IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!